# Google Map position Right_Center Not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map and want the position to `RIGHT_CENTER`.  But it is not working for me. Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Code:

```
var contact = { "lat": "****", "lon": "***" }; // Change a map coordinate here!

try {
    var mapContainer = $('#map');
    mapContainer.gmap3({
        action: 'addMarker',
        latLng: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
        map: {
            center: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER // This is not working 
            },
        },
    },   { action: 'setOptions', args: [{ scrollwheel: true }] }  );    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example or jsfiddle? Have you tried changing the `HORIZONTAL_BAR` to something else? Is the positionning still wrong?

Comment: *Note: No guarantees can be made that controls may not overlap given complicated layouts, though the API will attempt to arrange them intelligently.* From the API documentation. Maybe the *intelligent* positionning is causing your issue.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: Thanks for your reply. I am using Gmape 3. But I want the marker position in the Right_Center. Here is the fiddler link: http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/D7Wv5/1/ which is shared by Mr. Paulitto. SO can you please help me to get the marker in the Right_Center Position. In the fiddler code there is a line of code missing :  center: [contact.lat, contact.lon]. We set center from this.

Comment: What do you mean the *marker position in the right center*? Which marker? Please fork the fiddle and show us what you are trying to do...

Comment: @MrUpsidown : Thanks, for your reply. I am using marker in this to show the exact position. Now, I had solved it by changing the center location to some extent and it works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using gmap3 jquery plugin. You should specify all map options in `options` property there (I guess other options dont work as well), see [here](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/9-map/map-32).

Like this:

```
var mapContainer = $('#map');
mapContainer.gmap3({
    marker:{
        latLng: [45,-10], 
    },
    map: {
        options: {
            center: [45,-10],
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER // This is not working 
            }
        }
    },
},   { action: 'setOptions', args: [{ scrollwheel: true }] }  );
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/D7Wv5/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Options work for me. But I want the marker position in the Right_Center. So Can you please help me for solving this.

Comment: mapTypeControlOptions stands for map type control options, not marker. To include marker I guess you should use `marker` property (looking at [docs](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41) ). Updated code (and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/D7Wv5/2/)) to show how to include a marker

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by changing my code to some extent(i.e By changing the center position in the code posted by me).